# BigQuery scheduling Vs Cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to know while scheduling any Big Query recurring query; which one is the better option to choose; Big Query scheduler or Cloud Scheduler?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to execute queries with no dependencies then I would go the route of a scheduled query.  It would be the simplest approach as it handles creation of the underlying components necessary to execute the query on a schedule for you.

Alternatively if you were to use cloud scheduler, you would need to create the schedule, and cloud function(s) to execute the queries.

If you had dependencies in between queries or subsequent tasks that needed to be completed take a look at [cloud composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) or [workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) to help orchestrate.

Comment: Agree, Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Workflow is the best combo!